# I cannot make my default avatar to display male or female

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php

    function getAvatar($userid = 0, $size = null) {
        global $set;
        if($size)
            $size = "?s=$size";
        if(!$userid) {
            if($this->data->showavt) {
                return "$set->url/img/private.png";
            }
        else if($this->data->gender) {
                if(!$gender == 'Male'){
                    return "$set->url/img/male.png";
                }
                else {
                    return "$set->url/img/female.png";
                }
            }
        }
        $u = $this->db->getRow("SELECT `email`, `showavt`, `gender` FROM `".MLS_PREFIX."users` WHERE `userid` = ?i", $userid);

        if(!$u->showavt){   
            return "$set->url/img/private.png";
            }
        else if($u->gender) 
                return "$set->url/img/male.png";
            else    
                return "$set->url/img/female.png";

    }

?>
```

I cant manage to display the avatar if the user is male of female.
I did only manage to display the private avatar if the user hide their avatar.

Comment: What do you get in the `else if($this->data->gender)` part of your code?

Comment: For one thing, `!$gender == 'Male'` should be `!($gender == 'Male')`.  Aside from that, when you debug this where does the problem occur?  What are the runtime values of the things you're comparing?

Comment: `if (!$gender == 'Male')` should be `if ($this->data->gender == 'Male')`

Comment: My user_list.php with photos still load so I really dont know what the error is. The only reason why i know its not working, every user has gender, and the default avatar for female and male cant connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    function getAvatar($userid = 0, $size = null) {
        global $set;
        if($size)
            $size = "?s=$size";
        if(!$userid) {
            if($this->data->showavt) {
                return "$set->url/img/private.png";
            }
        else if($gender = $this->data->gender) {
                if($gender == 'Male'){
                    return "$set->url/img/male.png";
                }
                else {
                    return "$set->url/img/female.png";
                }
            }
        }
        $u = $this->db->getRow("SELECT `email`, `showavt`, `gender` FROM `".MLS_PREFIX."users` WHERE `userid` = ?i", $userid);

        if(!$u->showavt){   
            return "$set->url/img/private.png";
            }
        else if($u->gender) // If gender field in DB is not boolean than try $u->gender == 'Male'
                return "$set->url/img/male.png";
            else    
                return "$set->url/img/female.png";

    }

?>
```

Comment: No luck, all users still in male avatar except those I hide the avatar, the private avatar works.

Comment: Oh there it is, yes my gender field in my db is not in boolean. The $su->gender == 'Male' works. Thanks!